# Users with iOS sometimes don't see the option to allow our mobile app to access their location

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, mobile-application, ios-privacy-settings

We've built a mobile app for drivers that collects location data. As of a few months ago, half of our drivers no longer have see the option to "Always Allow" access to share location data to our app in their location privacy settings. Our mobile app doesn't event come up as an option for them to choose "Never" or "allow when app is in use" or "always allow". We've tested this with different versions of iphones and iOS but can't figure out why some users just don't have the option. Therefore we can't collect location data from those users. Images below show screenshots of two different iphone 13, both with the latest iOS 16.1.1 version.

Any idea whats happening?

[iphone with location privacy options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y72t1.png)
[iphone with NO location privacy options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld1p2.jpg)

We tried testing both phones with two different user cases: one user case chose to "allow all" location settings when the messages first pop up after downloading the app and setting up their account. The other user case we tested choosing "don't allow" in the first messages that popped up but that didn't change anything. We can't figure out why one user with the same iphone and ios version doesn't have the option to toggle location for our mobile app and the other user can.

Comment: The first line shown in your screen shot is "location access always"?

Comment: @Paulw11 there are two photos I've provided. One that shows location access always (this is how all iphones should be showing), and a different phone (same model and ios version) that doesn't show the option at all. We can't figure out why that is

Comment: If you don't see the location permission in settings then your app has never asked for location permission.  Check your logic where you request location access.

Comment: Our app asks for location permission to all drivers when they first download the app. The issue is that some drivers dont see the option in their settings after they're asked

Comment: If the permission section doesn't appear in app settings then I guarantee your app never asked.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you. I'll ask our tech team to review the logic and let you know what we find out.